# What is the formula that hadronization is not able to be resolved using pertubation theory?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, hadronization

(New in particle physics background in Computer science)

I read [image][image]
(source: https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C990809/docs/webber.pdf) that hadronization is not well undestood because pertubation theory is not able to be applied. Is the formulas in the image the ones for which the problem refers to?  Specifically the term $ D_i^h$

Comment: If you want to learn about particle physics, this is *not* where to start.

Comment: Thank you for the comment would you recommend some introductory material?

Comment: for introduction this might help https://home.cern/students-educators , book http://nuclphys.sinp.msu.ru/books/b/Griffiths.pdf . You need to learn the data before going into formulas